# ¿Cómo valido datos duplicados en un campo con Django forms?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Tengo un campo en la tabla de mi formulario que no debería recibir datos duplicados pero no sé cómo configurarlo ni dónde debería realizar dicha configuración.

model.py:

```
class Empleados(models.Model):

    OPCIONES_GENERO_CHOICES = (

        ('M', 'Masculino'),
        ('F', 'Femenino'),
    )

    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    ci = models.IntegerField()
    genero = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=OPCIONES_GENERO_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    cargo = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    creado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    documento = models.FileField(
        upload_to="archivo/",
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s'% (self.nombre)
```

el campo es `ci`, que es la cédula de identidad (id, dni, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo único que tienes que hacer es usar [`unique`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#unique) en el campo para el cual no quieres valores duplicados:

```
class Empleados(models.Model):

    OPCIONES_GENERO_CHOICES = (

        ('M', 'Masculino'),
        ('F', 'Femenino'),
    )

    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    ci = models.IntegerField(unique=True) # AQUÍ
    genero = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=OPCIONES_GENERO_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    cargo = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    creado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    documento = models.FileField(
        upload_to="archivo/",
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s'% (self.nombre)
```

Esto implica que Django no permita guardar valores duplicados para esa tabla. También, se crea un índice (index) para ese campo a nivel de base de datos.